# eliminating spaces in a string except for when they are in literal quotes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a project using windows forms and c#. In this project I need to take a string and turn it into a new one that has all of the spaces removed unless they have literal * around them.

I have managed to get rid of all the other types of white-spaces(tabs, cr, new lines). For this question I'm only talking about spaces from the spacebar. I had thought about using a method or loop, and I tried a couple of different ways, but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance, Carson

example:

```
string myString = "this is a test *a b c*this is a test*1 2 3* this is a test";
// through some method or loop would return this:
string newString = "thisisatest*a b c*thisisatest*1 2 3*thisisatest"
// notice how the spaces remain when they are in literal quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the characters and keep a flag that you toggle when you see a double quote and use that to determine if a space is kept or not.

```
bool quoted = false;
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(char c in myString) {
    if(!quoted && c == ' ')
        continue;
    if(c == '"')
        quoted = !quoted;
    builder.Append(c);
}

myString = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple like that. Mine was similar but didn't work. Thanks again.